# In GitBash having trouble assigning user name and email

Tags: git-bash

When I type `git config --global user.name "myusername"` I get

```
fatal: bad config file line 4 in c:/Users/anthony wiggins/.gitconfig
```

I tried un and reinstalling GitBash, my user name is my GitHub name `aawiggins314` and I thought that may be why and my Gitbash says `anthony wiggins@AAWIGGINS` and I thought that changing my user name may help.
My final idea is that gitconfig is not opening and if that's why how do i do that?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file and editing or removing line four?

Comment: I opened it (config)in Notepad and this is what I see:

Comment: [core]
 bare = false
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
 logallrefupdates = true

Comment: should I just delete line 4 and can I do that in Notepad

Comment: I just opened it again and got                                                                                [user]
name = Tony Wiggins'

git config --global user.name Tony
email = tonyw314@yahoo.com    which looks right until I use git config again and I get the line 4 message again

Comment: If you want to show the contents of `.gitconfig` add it to the post, not a comment -- it's really hard to tell what you mean in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: 1) [user]

2) name = aawiggins314


4) git config --global user.name aawiggins314

5) email = tonyw314@yahoo.com

Comment: One question I have is if I change it in TextNotepad will that change the actual file?

Comment: Im wondering if I have multiple .gitconfig files and theyre conflicting somehow?

Comment: No, the error message seems totally clear: line 4 in that file is wrong. If you need help modifying it, edit your original post and add the contents of the file there, _not_ into a comment as you've done so far.

Comment: I went into Notepad++ and made the following change, I added quotes at the front and back of aawiggins314 making it "aawiggins314" and then tried git config --global user.name again with the quotes and i get a line starting with >  Good?

Answer (score 0):

> My final idea is that gitconfig is not opening and if that's why how do i do that?

It can open but isn't interpreted fully by Git because of that line 4.

Once you have removed it, note that adding a user.name shouldn't need double-quotes (unless you have a space in it):

```
 git config --global user.name myusername
```